# mongodb how to maintain an unique array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am using `$push` to appends a value to an array.

```
connection.erp_datasets.erp_datasets.update_one({'erp_name': 'erp1'},
                                            {'$push': {'data_set': 'database1'}}, upsert=True)
```

The problem is whenever I run the query again, multiple `erp1` will be appended to the list,

```
"data_set" : [ 
    "erp1", 
    "erp1"
]
```

I am wondering how to maintain the array with unique values. so it doesn't matter how many times I executed the above query,`data_set` will only contain one `erp1`,

```
"data_set" : [ 
    "erp1"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $addToSet

connection.erp_datasets.erp_datasets.update_one({'erp_name': 'erp1'},
                                            {'$addToSet': {'data_set': 'database1'}}, upsert=True)